# PostgreSQL concatenate different attributes together to return a single value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE venue (id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('venue_id_seq'), building_code     building_code, floorNo int,  roomNo int,  width int, length int);
```

The function:

```
 CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION roomCode(_id int ) RETURNS text AS 
$$
 SELECT building_code + floorNo + roomNo FROM venue as v WHERE _id = v.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

How can I Concatenate certain attributes together?

Comment: SQL query can only give you tuples. If you want to concatenate the results, you have to do it by hand or use (for example) Python. Why do you want to concatenate these numbers?

Comment: I want "building_code", "floorNo" and "roomNo" to concatenate into text that the function can return. For example: IT 4 - 2. Where "building_code = IT", "floorNo = 4" and "roomNo = 2".

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this is the best way to do it, But I think it will get the job done:

You can use `SELECT TEXTCAT( param 1, param 2)`
If you want more than one attribute then you have to use a `TEXTCAT` within a `TEXTCAT` such as:

```
TEXTCAT( param 1, TEXTCAT(param 2, param3))
```

If your attributes are not of type text already then you will have to cast them to text as so:

```
attribute::text
```

So to answer your question in a whole:

```
SELECT TEXTCAT(building_code::text, TEXTCAT( floorNo::text , roomNo::text))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [string concatenation operator - `||`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html)

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION roomCode(_id int ) RETURNS text AS 
$$
 SELECT building_code || ' ' || floorNo::text || ' - ' || roomNo::text FROM venue as v WHERE _id = v.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1d8cd/1)